# Encoding data for neural network

Tags: encoding, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I have a question on what is the best way to encode (certain type of) data for neural network.

The data is two subsets of larger dataset (all possible values that a certain index can have, basically labels). So two player teams, that consist of some characters from all possible characters in game. Then the output is the end result of a battle (win, lose or tie).

For example we have possible characters [tank, healer, mage, spy], and the teams are known length subsets of the possible characters, for example [tank, healer], [tank, spy].

Also, one character can appear only once in a team (eg. in the example both teams can have tank, but one team cannot have two tanks)

I was thinking of encoding the data in a way, where the data is an array of length of two times the superset, and where indices of chosen player team members are set to true (or 1) and rest to false (0). This would end up with the examples looking like this:

```
    [tank, healer, mage, spy, tank, healer, mage, spy]
and [tank, healer,     ,    , tank,       ,     , spy]
______________________________________________________
    [   1,      1,    0,   0,    1,      0,    0,   1]
```

Is this a reasonable way of encoding data for neural network? The problem is, that if team size is small, and range of characters is large, most of the space is wasted with zeros, so is there a better way to encode this type data?

I'm also having a bad time trying to get the network to learn stuff, and getting more data is slow, so is there a way of augmenting this data? There may be some hidden and complex relationships in the two teams, so I figured that keeping the order the same every time would be good, but maybe it isn't?

Comment: Is there a reason why you've encoded it with 0s and 1s instead of just using an integer to indicate how many of what type were in a team? (2 tanks, 1 healer, 0 mages, 1 spy for instance)

Comment: Good point, in one team here can be only one character at a time. I'll edit it down.